# Pyspark Compare the iterable list of all keys and return the count of same elements

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with Pyspark on a data set with key value pair that looks like the following:

```
[(u'1', u'10'), (u'1', u'15'), (u'1', u'5'), (u'2', u'11'), (u'2', u'15'), (u'2', u'30'),  (u'3', u'10'), (u'3', u'5'), (u'3', u'11')]
```

The data could be interpreted as

```
1 => 10, 15, 5;  2 => 11, 15, 30;  3 => 10, 5, 11;
```

I am trying to compare the values of all the keys and find the count the same values. In the sample data, key 1 and 2 both have value 15, the output should return 1; key 1 and 3 both have value 10 and 5, the output should be 2... etc.

Expected output:

```
1, 2 => 1;  1, 3 => 2;  2, 3 => 1;
```

My thought is to group the data by key to get the iterable list and compare individual elements inside the list.

```
data1 = data.groupByKey()

data1.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()
```

The output of data1:

```
[(u'1', [u'10', u'15', u'15']), (u'2', [u'11', u'15', u'30']), (u'3', [u'10', u'5', u'11'])]
```

I am having trouble coming up with a way to iterate through the list and comparing the elements for all the keys. I would appreciate if anyone would know a way to do the iteration or have a suggestion on how to approach the problem in general. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can get the result with a loop over keys:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("common values")\
    .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

data = [(u'1', u'10'), (u'1', u'15'), (u'1', u'5'), (u'2', u'11'), (u'2', u'15'), (u'2', u'30'),  (u'3', u'10'), (u'3', u'5'), (u'3', u'11')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
rdd = rdd.groupByKey() \
           .mapValues(list)
print "data:\n", rdd.collect()
keys = rdd.map(lambda l: l[0]).collect()
print "keys:", keys
result = sc.emptyRDD()
for k in keys:
    values = rdd.filter(lambda l: l[0] == k)\
                .map(lambda l: l[1])
    values = set(values.collect()[0])
    rdd = rdd.filter(lambda l: l[0] != k).persist()
    # only compare unique pairs
    common = rdd.map(lambda l: [(l[0], k), len(set(l[1]).intersection(values))])
    result = result.union(common)
print "results:", result.collect()
```

Construct a set of keys, and for each key:

- construct a set of corresponding values
- for each key (except for the "used" keys) check how many elements
  are in common

It works well for this tiny test data set (spark 2.0.2, python 2.7 here), not sure how well does it
scale.

```
results: [[(u'3', u'1'), 2], [(u'2', u'1'), 1], [(u'2', u'3'), 1]]
```